# How to set the UIButton tint color of a system image when pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton that uses System icons as images, at the minute I am setting the tint colour using the following

```
buttonLogin?.tintColor = Globals().buttonFontColor
```

Now when I go to press the button the highlighted state changes the tint colour to a dark grey. I would like to change this so that when I press the button the colour can be set by me. I have tried subclassing the button with no luck.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.green
        }
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

Can someone point me in the right directions thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also disable adjusting image property:

```
buttonLogin?.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

Now grey effect should be vanished